# Graph should not be move if not zoomed

Tags: ios, ios4, core-plot

I am using core plot to draw graph. Graph moves always whether it is zoomed or not. But I want like it should not move until it is zoomed. In zooming state we should allow panning(moving left/right) to see the whole graph.
Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I can think of several ways to do this:

1. Disable user interaction when zoomed out. Enable it when the user zooms in.
2. Set the `globalXRange` and `globalYRange` on the plot space. The plot won't scroll outside these ranges no matter how far out you zoom.
3. Use a plot space delegate. Implement the `-plotSpace:willChangePlotRangeTo:forCoordinate:` delegate method. If the proposed range is outside the desired scrolling range, modify the range to your preferred range before returning it.

Comment: Sorry but if i will disable the interaction then how user can zoom. If I am not wrong then you are talking about 'allowsUserInteraction' flag of scatter plot.

Comment: @Armaan, correct. I didn't know how you were zooming the graph—it could be done in response to a button press or other event, too.